# How do I pass parameter string in a URL to a standard event in a Facebook pixel?

Tags: facebook

I am using teachable.com to sell courses and want to track conversions with the Facebook Ads pixel.

Typically you add something like this to the thankyou page:

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'Purchase', { 
    currency: 'USD', 
    value: 18.00, 
    content_name: 'courseName' 
    content_category: 'courseCategory 
});
</script>
```

But because my customers can use coupon codes the value is often different.

Now the thankyou URL contains the final_price parameter:

```
http:/mycoursesite.com/courses/plug-n-play-routine-basic/purchased?purchased=113315&purchased_course_id=77235&purchased_list_price=1500&final_price=0&currency=EUR&payment_method=coupon&user_id=884307&email=bj%40stagebound.de&purchased_at=1469815636&is_recurring=false&sale_id=2210078
```

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    currency: '$currency',
    value: $final_price,
    course: '$purchased_course_id'

});
</script>
```

Is there a way to get the final_price value into the facebook pixel value parameter?

Comment: `course: '$purchased_course_id'` – that will of course only work if the `<script>` block was output by your PHP code (and you have pulled the parameter value out of $_GET and put it into this variable first) – that the case?

Comment: No, that is not the case.  How would I pull the parameter of the $_GET and put it into the variable? And what would the PHP code be to output that `<script>` block?

Comment: This is getting too broad, and it has little to do with the `facebook` tag either. If you don’t know how to handle GET parameters and how to generate HTML or script output with PHP yet, then please go read up on this stuff beforehand.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. For clarity on my search, in my PHP code I would first pull the parameter string value from the URL with some kind of $_GET code. To output this value into the HTML throug my Facebook Javascript I need more PHP code. But CBroe you say "This is getting too broad..." but it hasn't gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: Of course it is getting too broad if we have to explain trivial stuff such as how to output the content of a variable via PHP to people here. That's what the manual and beginner tutorials are for.